# How to search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I want to search in elasticsearch.
I am using mongoosastic as my driver for elasticsearch.
Where I want to search a string whether it exists in one field and I want to search one more field whether it should match exactly. How can I do it in mongoosastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) feature of Elastic search.

I don't know where you're stuck in the process, but I'll try to describe the process.

To have a model indexed into Elasticsearch simply add the plugin.

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'),
   mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic'),
   Schema       = mongoose.Schema

var User = new Schema({
   name: String,
   country: String,
   age: Number,
   email: String,
   city: String})

User.plugin(mongoosastic)
```

Then you can perform an ES search on your model, but first you format your query. Let's say you want every user living in England, but not in London, and you would like to match users between 30 and 40 years old :

```
var query = {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "term" : { "country" : "england" }
        },
        "must_not" : {
            "city" : { "city" : "london" }
        },
        "should" : {
            "range" : {
                "age" : { "from" : 30, "to" : 40}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will get user that don't match your query in term on age, but ES will use a scoring system to sort the results.

To finish you send your query to ES and process the results

```
User.search(query, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        //Handle error
    }

    var results = users.hits.hits;

    //work with your hits
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paradise228, Is there any way to support function score queries using mongoosastic, I tried to find in the doc but bad luck.